# Why is there a difference in the way that D3 processes a hex colour code vs. a colour name during locally-hosted transitions?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I was working on a D3 map, and indicated several large cities in the U.S. using circle SVG elements. Pretty standard. I transitioned both circle size (i.e., the radius, or the "r" attribute) and circle colour. Oddly enough, I found that **when I used the HTML colour name, "DeepPink", the colour transition occurred immediately, whereas the size transition took the time I specified (1000ms). When I used the hex code for the colour — #FF1493 — everything transitioned without any issues**. Does anyone know why this would be the case?

The first code example below is the version where the colour changes gradually, transitioning from blue to pink at the same time as

```
        svg.selectAll("circle")
            .transition()
            .delay(300)
            .duration(1000)
            .ease("circle")
            .style({
                "fill": "#FF1493",
                "stroke": "white",
                "opacity": 0.9,
                "stroke-width": 0.7
            })
            .attr({
                "cx": function(d) { circleXCoord = projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0]; return circleXCoord},
                "cy": function(d) { circleYCoord = projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1]; return circleYCoord},
                "r": function (d) { return rScale(parseFloat(d.value));}
            })
```

In the second example, the colour transition occurs all at once after the 300ms delay while the radius transition occurs as expected.

```
        svg.selectAll("circle")
            .transition()
            .delay(300)
            .duration(1000)
            .ease("circle")
            .style({
                "fill": "DeepPink",
                "stroke": "white",
                "opacity": 0.9,
                "stroke-width": 0.7
            })
            .attr({
                "cx": function(d) { circleXCoord = projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0]; return circleXCoord},
                "cy": function(d) { circleYCoord = projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1]; return circleYCoord},
                "r": function (d) { return rScale(parseFloat(d.value));}
            })
```

The only difference between the two code snippets, literally, is the fill value — one's a hex code and the other is the colour name. Why does this happen?

**EDIT:** note that when copied my code to a gist and viewed the [block (http://bl.ocks.org/iblind/c15096f98636dcce7428)](http://bl.ocks.org/iblind/c15096f98636dcce7428), this result didn't manifest, and everything worked as normal. When I'd hosted things locally using python's SimpleHTTPServer, the aberration above became noticeable. I realize this narrows the scope of the question somewhat, but if anyone knows why this sort of behaviour would be affected by hosting locally vs. using blocks, I'd be very interested to hear it.

Comment: Can you post a complete example? What does the svg code consist of?

Comment: It works for me. Both ways behave equally. What is the starting value of your transition? Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @MrLister So I threw everything up as a gist, and linked to it [as a block](http://bl.ocks.org/iblind/c15096f98636dcce7428). Here's the really strange thing: locally, when I'm running a SimpleHTTPServer through python, the colour transition is as I've described. When I look at my block, everything is silky smooth and works as it should... Really strange. Am I the only one that's getting this difference?

Comment: @altocumulus Yup. I went from:
#0000FF to DeepPink to #0000FF, but here's the kicker—it's only the case locally, when I run a SimpleHTTPServer using python. Editing the main post to reflect this.

Comment: As implied by @altocumulus this type of problem - where a transition jumps to the end value - is due to the starting value being undefined or invalid. What happens if you change the colour string to" deeppink"?

Comment: @CoolBlue Ah, I hadn't realized. That's odd, though — the starting value was blue, indicated by "#0000FF", after which I transitioned to the "DeepPink". It's a little difficult to word it, but the block I'd mentioned at the end of the question should give you an idea of what I mean.

Comment: put a callback on the start event of the transition and log the fill attribute to see if it's valid in the situation that produces the behaviour. If the value comes back null, then the problem shifts to why the colour isn't parsed?